# Multithreading puzzle in cpp

Tags: synchronization

```
void BalanceTransfer(Account &FromAccount, Account &ToAccount, double amount)
{
    FromAccount.Substract(amount);
    ToAccount.Add(amount);
    //What is the best way to protect this function if there are 100 threads calling this function for 1000's of accounts...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a mutex in each account. Before the transaction, lock both mutexes (and of course release them afterwards). The locking order is important; to avoid deadlock you need a defined locking order, eg always lock the account with the lowest account number first.